# Issue when using loc to filter a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm attempting to find rows that contain values from two different columns that I specify.

The problem arises when I specify the values using a variable (which contains a string) vs just using a `str` object.

Example:

```
>> new_df = df.loc[(df['event_id'] == ev) & (df['station'] == sta)]
Empty DataFrame
>> type(ev)
<class 'str'>
```

But if I instead directly insert strings before the `==` it works just fine and prints out a new dataframe with 4 rows.

`>> new_df = df.loc[(df['event_id'] == 'A239') & (df['station'] == 'WON')]`

What the issue?

Comment: Can you provide an example that can reproduce your problem? Otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: @TYZ I cannot unfortunately, wasn't sure if I was not doing something obvious. The variables I'm inputting are strings, and when I manually input them they're definitely strings as can see in the question for the `new_df` line, so I'm stumped. I'll post an answer when I find a workaround.